# Calling a function within another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, module, scope

I've read a few SO answers regarding this, but nothing seems to be useful.

I have a module in a React-Redux-Google Maps project exporting a function like this:

```
export default function(google, map, store) {
  // Main module functionality
}
```

This function is imported into my `initMap` module, and called with `google`, `map`, and `store`. Thus, this function is able to interact with the map, e.g. create Google Maps markers, polylines, etc.

Within this function, I created a helper function to clear the map. I can do this by referencing rendered objects and calling their methods `.setMap(null)` (as per Google Maps' API documentation). However, I'd like to export this helper function so I can import it in my React components and bind it to the `onClick` handlers.

I know I can't export a helper function from within an exported function. Neither can I call the helper function directly. Nor can I bring the helper function outside of the main function (i.e. they are in the same scope), because it then loses access to the `google`, `map`, and `store` variables.

The only solution I think is possible is that I restructure the main (default export) function to return an object:

```
{
  main: main,
  helper: helper
}
```

where `main` and helper are sub-functions. This way, both sub-functions can access the `google`, `map`, and `store` variables, which will be in scope.

I.e.:

```
export default function(google, map, store) {
  function main() {
    // Main module functionality
  }

  function helper() {
    // Helper module functionality
  }

  return {
    main: main,
    helper: helper
  };
}
```

Is this feasible/bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

If the two functions are not closely related, it makes more sense to store the functions in different files and import both.

If they are more closely related, which seems to be the case here, you could store them in as static methods of a class, and export the class instead. This option would be helpful for organizing your related functions into methods of a helper class, and would get the job done simply.

```
export default class {
  static main() {
    // Main module functionality
  }

  static helper() {
    // Helper module functionality
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the class solution is conceptually very similar to the object solution, right? Are there any benefits/costs to choosing one over the other? E.g. `<className>.main()` vs `<objectName>.main()`.

Comment: Its true that they are very similar, but the class solution is shorter, and slightly easier to write and read, especially if you were grouping many functions rather than just two. Whichever you choose is up to you.

Comment: I've been experimenting with your suggestion (i.e. the `class` implementation), but facing some issues. I'm unable to set properties from `static main()` (Cannot assign to read only property '<propertyName>' of function 'class <className>). Yet, if I instantiate using the `new` keyword, I'm unable to access static methods.

The problem is that I need to share variables across methods, which means I need to set them as class properties.